# Match strings in two lists in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The question is simple and can be done in thousand of ways. But since I am learning Java 8, I would like to do it in the Java 8 way.

I have two list of strings, ex:

```java
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("A", "D", "E");
```

I want to take the first element from `list1` and check if the string is present in `list2` and produce a `Map<Boolean, String>`. Something like this:

```java
Map<Boolean, String> resultMap = list1.stream().collect(partial -> Collectors.partitioningBy(list2.stream().filter(existing -> matchString(partial, existing))));

private static boolean matchString(String partial, String existing) {
    return partial.equals(existing);
}
```

The above code has a compilation error at `matchString(partial, existing)`:

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: '', required:
>   'java.lang.String'

Few things to note is that, the in my actual scenario it's not a simple list of string but a more complicated object and that object doesn't override `equals` or `hashcode` method.

I very well know that this can be done in different ways. But could somebody please let me know how do we use `Collectors.partitioningBy` in this particular scenario.

Comment: You haven't explained what the `Map<Boolean, String>` represents. All we have is a snippet of code that doesn't compile.

Comment: What @shmosel said: What the mapping is to represent is unclear.  As written, the mapping would have at most two elements, True mapped to a string value and False mapped to a string value.  I'm guessing that the mapping is intended to answer whether a particular value of the first list is a member of the second list, in which case at the very least the mapping should be typed as Map<String, Boolean>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) you can get `Map<Boolean, List<String>>`. From `partitioningBy` doc:

> Returns a Collector which partitions the input elements according to a `Predicate`, and organizes them into a `Map<Boolean, List<T>>`.

In your case:

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = list1.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(list2::contains));
```

In case of more complex object that doesn't override `equals`/`hashcode` you can do comparison by some specific field. Assuming you have something like:

```
class ComplexObj {
    private String id;
    ...
}

Map<Boolean, List<ComplexObj>> map = list1.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(obj -> list2.stream()
                    .map(ComplexObj::getId)
                    .anyMatch(id -> id.equals(obj.getId()))));
```

Comment: Thank you, but `contains' wont work because hashcode and equals are not overriden

Comment: @RahulDevMishra your question says you have two lists of `String`. If you actually have objects without proper hashCode/equals implementations, you should include that into your question, resp. you should not talk about strings in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Find my implementation below using Collectors.partitioningBy. I use List.contains() method for predicate and it works fine. Kindly try and share feedback/suggestions. Thanks.

```
package net.javapedia.streams;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PartitioningByEx1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("A", "D", "E");

        list1.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(item -> list2.contains(item)))
                .forEach((key, val) -> System.out.println(key + "-->>" + val));
    }

}
```

**Program output:**

[image: Output]